# Angular test abstract Observable

Tags: angular

I have a service with an observable declarated (without any methods to trigger it):

```
abstract onSessionTimeout$: Observable<void>;
```

and a component with a subscription to that observable changes:

```
private _subscribeToSessionEvents(): void {
    this.nameService.onSessionTimeout$.subscribe(() =>
      console.log('I need to test this')
    );
  }
```

How could I do a test of that? I tried to mock it, but It seems not to work (maybe the sintax) (.next send me an error: Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Observable')

```
const nameServiceMock = {
  onSessionTimeout$: new Subject<void>(),
};

providers: [
  { provide: NameService, useValue: nameServiceMock }
],


  it('should do something when session timeout', () => {
    const nameService = TestBed.inject(NameService);
    spyOn(console, 'log');
    component.nameService.onSessionTimeout$.next();
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith('I need to test this');
  });
```

How could I test it?

Comment: There is some spanish text, could you please re-phrase it in English?

Comment: ops sorry, done

Comment: instead of `const nameService = TestBed.inject(NameService);` take the mock instance `const nameService = nameServiceMock;`

Comment: Yes is correct (I was confusing), that works perfect thanks. Can you put it as answer to vote you?